# DJango user not logging out

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I'm new to DJango and I'm trying to make a user auth. My login is working fine but my user isn't logging out.

My Logout view is:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class LogoutView(generic.View):
    @staticmethod
    def get(request):
        if User.is_authenticated:
            # Debug statement
            print('if')
            logout(request)
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            return redirect('index')
```

My url is working fine because when i go to **/logout/**, My debug statement executes

but `if User.is_authenticated:` always returns an object(true).

How can I resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: `User` is the class, not the current user. You want `request.user.is_authenticated`.

Comment: There's already a [`LogoutView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView) that comes with Django. It would be easier to use that than write your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User.is_authenticated is not what you should do. User is class, show it will have objects which is shown on your request which is already there, and it has nothing to do with the user who is serfing. While, `request` is the object of the user which carry many things one of them is `user`.

It should be:

```
request.user.is_authenticated:
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can u tell me how can I use the same if statement in template?

Comment: As you already are in request inside templates, you can simply do: ```{% if user.is_authenticated %}```